# windows phone 8.1 invokescript

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

In Windows Phone 8 you could use:

```
(string)browser.InvokeScript("eval", "document.title.toString()");
```

to return page title from browser.

How would you go about doing this in the new WP8.1's API

Comment: Are you targeting Silverlight or WinRT? In Silverlight you have still WebBrowser, in WinRT you have [WebView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview).

Comment: I was targeting WinRT. My goal is to make my app universal. Would you recommend targeting WinRT or Silverlight?

Comment: If you want to make an universal app, then WinRT is a good choice. Otherwise it depends on your needs, specific of the app and more. Apps written in Silverlight and WinRT will both run on WP8.1.

Comment: thanks I'll stick with winRT then. How do I use the invokescript method in webview to return the page's title?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For anyone looking for the answer I got it to work using

```
string[] args = { "document.title;" };
string foo = await webView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", args);
```

Answer (score 0):

[InvokeScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402838%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) is still supported in silverlight for windows phone 8.1

Comment: Sorry I was targeting WinRT

Comment: How can I use the invokescript method in webview to return the page's title?